# iOS: Migrating Cocoapods from Dynamic Libraries to Static Libraries

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to transition from dynamic libraries (via use_frameworks!) to static libraries in a project that the uses cocoapods to handle external dependencies. The project is a combo of swift & objc.

One of these dependencies is an internal swift cocoapod. However, when I try to build, I get the following message:

`Cannot load underlying module <our_internal_cocoapod>`

Additionally, the `ProjectName-swift.h` is not found, I am assuming it is not being generated.

Things I've tried:
1. cleaning & building
2. deleting derived data
3. reinstalling cocoa pods

All to no avail. How can I resolve this? Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Static libraries don't provide module access by default.

CocoaPods 1.5.0 introduced `use_modular_headers!` to still provide module support with static libraries. Details in the [release notes](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.5.0/).

If you run into issues with that, you may want to try the 1.6.0 beta which has some bug fixes in this area.